# yes, constructor return that is current instance but we cannot use return type. is it true?

Tags: java, c++, constructor

yes,  constructor return that is current instance (You cannot use return type yet it returns a value) !  is this true ? means constructor really return a value ?

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly. I would say that `new` returns a value, the constructor is passed to, and invoked by, `new` (internally to the JVM) and actually sets up the instance.

To be even more precise see [JLS-12.5 Creation of New Class Instances](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.5), which says in part

> Just before a reference to the newly created object is returned as the result, the indicated constructor is processed to initialize the new object using the following procedure:
>
> 1. Assign the arguments for the constructor to newly created parameter variables for this constructor invocation.
> 2. If this constructor begins with an explicit constructor invocation (§8.8.7.1) of another constructor in the same class (using this), then evaluate the arguments and process that constructor invocation recursively using these same five steps. If that constructor invocation completes abruptly, then this procedure completes abruptly for the same reason; otherwise, continue with step 5.
> 3. This constructor does not begin with an explicit constructor invocation of another constructor in the same class (using this). If this constructor is for a class other than Object, then this constructor will begin with an explicit or implicit invocation of a superclass constructor (using super). Evaluate the arguments and process that superclass constructor invocation recursively using these same five steps. If that constructor invocation completes abruptly, then this procedure completes abruptly for the same reason. Otherwise, continue with step 4.
> 4. Execute the instance initializers and instance variable initializers for this class, assigning the values of instance variable initializers to the corresponding instance variables, in the left-to-right order in which they appear textually in the source code for the class. If execution of any of these initializers results in an exception, then no further initializers are processed and this procedure completes abruptly with that same exception. Otherwise, continue with step 5.
> 5. Execute the rest of the body of this constructor. If that execution completes abruptly, then this procedure completes abruptly for the same reason. Otherwise, this procedure completes normally.

Comment: oke thank you sir ..means new returns the newly created instance

Comment: The distinction isn't very obvious in most C-like languages, but if you use Objective C you have allocation (`new`) and initialization (the constructor) in two separate steps.

Comment: It's not common in C++, but you can do it in two steps there, too: `malloc(sizeof(T))` or `new char[sizeof(T)]` to allocate and `new(ptr) T()` to initialize.